# Extract a value from a list of InterpolatingFunction

Tags: differential-equations, replacement

By running the code

```
n = 5;
U[t_] := Table[Subscript[u, i][t], {i, 0, n}];
lines = NDSolve[{eqns, initc}, U[t], {t, 0, T}]
```

I get the output

```
{{u_0[t]->InterpolatingFunction[{{0.`,5.`}},"<>"][t], 
  u_1[t]->InterpolatingFunction[{{0.`,5.`}},"<>"][t],
  u_2[t]->InterpolatingFunction[{{0.`,5.`}},"<>"][t], 
  u_3[t]->InterpolatingFunction[{{0.`,5.`}},"<>"][t], 
  u_4[t]->InterpolatingFunction[{{0.`,5.`}},"<>"][t], 
  u_5[t]->InterpolatingFunction[{{0.`,5.`}},"<>"][t]}}
```

(it's the solution of a system of ODEs that I obtain by discretizing a PDE with the method of lines).
Now I would like to extract a particular value for each function, for example `u_2[0.5]` but I'm not managing to do that. Can someone help me?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Try $u_2\[0.5\] \tt{/. lines}$

Comment: The syntax `NDSolve[{eqns, initc}, U, {t, 0, T}]` might be more useful to you, for starters...

Comment: Hint: if you put @Sasha and J.M. advices together you get your answer ;-)

Comment: The first several examples in the help documentation for `NDSolve` show you how.

Comment: Thank you everyone, but it's still not working. Maybe it is because I actually initialized the function U[t] in the beginning as U[t_] := Table[Subscript[u, i][t], {i, 0, n}];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple working example:

```
n = 5;
T = 100;
U[t_] := Table[Subscript[u, i][t], {i, 0, n}];
eqns = Table[Derivative[1][Subscript[u, i]][t] == 0, {i, 0, n}];
initc = Table[Subscript[u, i][0] == 1, {i, 0, n}];
lines = NDSolve[{eqns, initc}, U[t], {t, 0, T}];

U[t] /. First@lines /. (t -> .5)
```

> {1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.}

Alternatively:

```
vars = Table[Subscript[u, i], {i, 0, n}]
sol = NDSolve[{eqns, initc}, vars, {t, 0, T}]
#[t] & /@ vars /. First@lines /. (t -> .5)
```

> {1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.}

Comment: I don't know how to thank you, really. Grazie! :)